# Prove minimizing angle in construction

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I am a computer science student currently working on his master thesis. I stumbled across a geometric problem that seems obvious but I couldn't prove it for weeks.

I attached a picture with the construction and will describe it below.

[image]

- Assume that we have a circle C with radius r = 1.
- M is the center of C.
- A point v is placed inside C and v!=M.
- Assume without loss of generality that v is placed on the same horizontal axis as M and that this axis is the x-axis of the coordinate system.
- the distance between M and v is called d (Note: $0<d<1$)
- Two additional points are placed on the circumference of C.
- the perpendicular bisector of the line $\overline{u_2u_1}$ goes through M
- The angle (u_2,v,u_1) is 90 degrees and the dashed line is bisecting that angle.
- $\phi$ is then the angle at v between the dashed line and the X-Axis.

The big question is now: 
Assuming $\phi$ can be changed from $0^\circ$ to $180^\circ$, which value for $\phi$ minimizes d'?

The answer is obviously $0^\circ$ but I want to prove that.

This is my current approach:

- use the triangle M,V,u_2 to compute $\overline{vu_2}$
- use the triangle M,V,u_1 to compute $\overline{vu_1}$
- use Pythagoras to compute $\overline{u_1u_2}$
- d' is minimized if $\overline{u_1u_2}^2$ is minimized

I will provide the values in much more detail below but I think a trigonometry expert can maybe give me a hint by looking at the construction only.

Here are the values (remember that r=1 and d is a constant:

Compute the values directly from $\phi$:
$$
\gamma=135^\circ-\phi \\
\gamma'=135^\circ+\phi \\
$$

First triangle to compute $a = \overline{vu_2}$:
$$
\beta =\arcsin{(d\sin{(\gamma)})} \\
\alpha =180^\circ-\beta-\gamma \\
a = \frac{\sin{(\alpha)}}{\sin{(\gamma)}} \\
$$

Second triangle to compute $a' = \overline{vu_1}$:
$$
\beta' =\arcsin{(d\sin{(\gamma')})} \\
\alpha'=180^\circ-\beta'-\gamma' \\
a' = \frac{\sin{(\alpha')}}{\sin{(\gamma')}} \\
$$

Use $a$ and $a'$ to compute $b=\overline{u_1u_2}$:
$$
b =\sqrt{a^2+a'^2} \\
$$

At this point I need to somehow show that $\phi=0$ minimizes $b$. Then it is just a small step to argue that minimizing $b$ minimizes $d'$.

I would really appreciate a solution or a useful hint on how to prove that $\phi=0^\circ$ minimizes $d'$.

Thanks in advance, Hendrik